# mssql like operand can not run correctly node.js and express

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

```js
router.post('/doktorismiAra', function (req, res, next) {
  var doktoradisoyadiA=req.body.doktoradisoyadi
  console.log(doktoradisoyadiA);

  sql.connect(dbTelefon, function (err) {
      if (err)
          console.log(err);

      var sqlRequest = new sql.Request();
      
      var sqlQery="SELECT * FROM doktorkayit WHERE doktoradisoyadi LİKE ?"+'%'+doktoradisoyadiA+'%';

      sqlRequest.query(sqlQery, function(err,data){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        console.log(data);
        console.table(data.recordset);
        console.log(data.rowsAffected);
        console.log(data.recordset[0]);
        sql.close();
      });
  });
});
```

'''info: ErrorMessageToken {
      name: 'ERROR',
      event: 'errorMessage',
      number: 4145,
      state: 1,
      class: 15,
      message: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'LİKE'.",
      serverName: 'DESKTOP-Q6EC342\SQLEXPRESS',
      procName: '',
      lineNumber: 1
    }
'''

Comment: isn't the query wrong? why do you need the `?`? where are the quotes? the total query would be `"SELECT * FROM doktorkayit WHERE doktoradisoyadi LIKE ?%expr%"` which is wrong query. and Why unicode `İ` in LIKE?

Comment: var sqlQery="SELECT * FROM doktorkayit WHERE doktoradisoyadi LIKE ?%s%";
then    message: "Incorrect syntax near '?'." İ is my fault, turkish keybord.

Comment: var sqlQery="SELECT * FROM doktorkayit WHERE doktoradisoyadi LIKE '%s%'"; this is running

Comment: var doktoradisoyadiA=req.body.doktoradisoyadi;var sqlQery="SELECT * FROM doktorkayit WHERE doktoradisoyadi LIKE '%"+doktoradisoyadiA+"%' "; and running with variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/doktorismiAra', function (req, res, next) {
```

var doktoradisoyadiA=req.body.doktoradisoyadi;
  console.log(doktoradisoyadiA);

sql.connect(dbTelefon, function (err) {
      if (err)
          console.log(err);

```
  var sqlRequest = new sql.Request();

  var sqlQery="SELECT * FROM doktorkayit WHERE doktoradisoyadi LIKE '%"+doktoradisoyadiA+"%' ";

  sqlRequest.query(sqlQery, function(err,data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
    console.table(data.recordset);
    console.log(data.rowsAffected);
    console.log(data.recordset[0]);
    sql.close();
  });
```

});
});